# Removing second last character (hyphen) from a string

Tags: php

I have a string like:

```
01-17-11-4
```

and want to get like:

```
01-17-114
```

How to do that in php?

I have tried following:

```
  substr_replace(implode('-', str_split($student->account_no, 2)), "", -1)
```

but it remove the last character like:

```
01-17-11-
```

Comment: Your title (asking how to remove the second-last character specifically) and your example code (doing something that's aware this string is a `-`-separated sequence of parts, and seemingly trying to remove the last part) don't match. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @MarkAmery, the title matches the *I have a string like:* and *and want to get like:* exactly, the code is a case of *I have tried following:* which means OP recognises that the code is wrong.

Comment: @NigelRen That really depends upon how fixed the format of the string is. Might that final segment sometimes have more than one digit, and if so, does the OP still want to remove the final hyphen instead of the penultimate character? The code attempt is suggestive that the answer might be "yes, the objective is really to remove the final hyphen", but the title is suggestive that the answer is "no, the objective is specifically to remove the penultimate character", and the example string gives no clue either way. Given the contradictory clues, we can only guess at the asker's real intent.

Comment: @MarkAmery, it would be possible to apply the same logic to hundreds (if not thousands) of questions, you see it all the time people making assumptions about what they think OP wants.  But as for *title is suggestive that the answer is "no"* - there is nothing suggestive about it - it is clear and the example is clear.  As for *we can only guess at what the correct solution is* again I think the comment under the answer *Yes that's what I'm looking for* might also help.

Comment: Nigel, if all that were here were the title and the example, I'd agree with you. But @FranzGleichmann successfully (and entirely unhelpfully) induced the OP to add sprinkle some broken code into their previously clear question, and that attempt doesn't square with everything else here - the logic it's trying to implement looks to me like "remove the final separator" rather than "remove the penultimate character".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) which allows you to take parts of a string this first chops off the last 2 characters (using -2 as the length) and then adds the last character back on...

```
echo substr($student->account_no, 0, -2).substr($student->account_no, -1);
```

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for..Thanks.